# NSum: Summand (or its derivative) is not numerical at point

Tags: summation, maximum

I am experiencing a problem in evaluating the maximum of a function that is defined as a sum

```
 G[φ_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := 
 8*Sum[((V[{t}]*Cos[φ/2]*(t/1.764))/Sqrt[(V[{t}]^2*Cos[φ/2]^2) + (((2*i) + 1)*π)^2]
 *ArcTan[(V[t]*Sin[φ/2])/Sqrt[(V[{t}]^2*Cos[φ/2]^2) + (((2*i) + 1)*π)^2]]), {i, 0, Infinity}]
```

I am able to evaluate the numerical value of this function setting `φ` and t.

Then, I define the function:

```
 L[t_] := φ /. NMaximize[N[G[φ, t]], φ]
```

To evaluate the maximum of the function varying in phi obtained by fixing t.
When I try to evaluate the numerical value of this function I get the error message:

[image: Error: Summand (or its derivative) is not numerical at point i = 0]

But it then gives me the right value. How can I fix this error? I need to plot the function and use it to fit experimental data.

Here the full code I used:

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := 2*\[Pi]*(\!\(\*
StyleBox[
SubsuperscriptBox["\[Sum]", 
RowBox[{"i", "=", "0"}], "\[Infinity]"],
FontSize->48]\(\*
StyleBox["(",
FontSize->48]\*
StyleBox[
RowBox[{
FractionBox["1", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", "*", "i"}], ")"}], "+", "1"}], ")"}], "*", 
StyleBox["\[Pi]",
FontSize->48]}]], "-", 
FractionBox["1", 
SqrtBox[
RowBox[{
SuperscriptBox["a", "2"], "+", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", "*", "i"}], ")"}], "+", "1"}], ")"}], "*", 
StyleBox["\[Pi]",
FontSize->48]}], ")"}], "2"]}]]]}],
FontSize->36]\*
StyleBox[")",
FontSize->36]\)\))

V[t_] := a /. FindRoot[f[a] == Log[(1/t)], {a, 1.4}]

L[t_] := NMaximize[N[G[\[CurlyPhi], t]], \[CurlyPhi]]
```

Comment: What is `V[{t}]`?

Comment: Please do not post images of your work, especially when all or some of the images display at a size that make them difficult to read. Please post your actual Mathematica code in the form of text that can be copied and pasted into a Mathematica notebook.

Comment: I posted all the part of the code I used. Thank you for your interest.